# «Так(,) чтобы...» — когда нужна запятая в начале предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Конструкция **Так(,) чтобы...** — отделяется ли запятыми в начале предложения?
Например:
**Покажите, на что способны. Так(,) чтобы вас заметили.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Покажите, на что способны. Так чтобы вас заметили.

Это парцелляция (деление на части) сложноподчиненного предложения с придаточным цели, а ТАК ЧТОБЫ - вариант целевого союза (ТАК ЧТОБЫ, С ТЕМ ЧТОБЫ, ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ).

Нужно отличать от сочетания ТАК + ЧТОБЫ.

http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=728 *Нужно воспитать в себе постоянную готовность поступать, действовать, вести себя с людьми так, чтобы в первую очередь позаботиться об их удобстве, а не о своем.* Л. Кассиль.

Comment: И здесь тоже ясно. :) Спасибо!

Comment: Это здорово, что **и здесь** Вам тоже все ясно-ясненько! Но ясность Ваша очень странная: Вы задали 29 (на сегодня) вопросов — и ни одного не приняли, половину — даже не оценили (как этот). Из спасиба шубу не сошьешь — скоро Вам просто перестанут отвечать.