# Запятушонка нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

`Перед каждым абзацем текста вставить разрывы (ctrl+enter)(,) так, чтобы каждый абзац начинался с новой страницы.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Перед каждым абзацем текста вставить разрывы (ctrl+enter) **так, чтобы** каждый абзац начинался с новой страницы.*

Это СПП со значением **образа действия и цели**, местоименно-союзная связь ***ТАК...ЧТОБЫ***, запятая ставится.

**Примечание**

Нерасчлененный союз ***ТАК ЧТОБЫ*** со значением **цели** тоже возможен, о чем говорится  **[Справочнике](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=728).**

Вопрос по союзу ***ТАК ЧТОБЫ***: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456566/Так-чтобы-когда-нужна-запятая-в-начале-предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456566/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: I forgot to accept your reply.

Answer (score 1):

***Перед каждым абзацем текста вставить разрывы (ctrl+enter) так, чтобы каждый абзац начинался с новой страницы***.

Запятую перед *так* нет оснований ставить. Посмотрим без вставки:

*Перед каждым абзацем текста вставить разрывы так, чтобы каждый абзац начинался с новой страницы*.

Перед *так* запятая не требуется, ни что не заставляет эту запятую стоять там.

Следовательно, и с вставкой не нужно ставить:

*Перед каждым абзацем текста вставить разрывы (ctrl+enter) так, чтобы каждый абзац начинался с новой страницы*.